# React Динамический Роутинг. Как пробросить нужные props в элемент вызова

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как передать нужные значения в новый компонент рендеринга ? Есть такой простой пример

```js
let state = {
  booksDescription: [{
      id: 1,
      bookName: "Понедельник начинается в субботу",
      urlAddress: "Monday-starts-on-Saturday",
      bookInSection: 1,
      authorNumber: 2
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      bookName: "Гарри Поттер и Орден Феникса",
      urlAddress: "Harry-Potter-and-the-Order-of-the-Phoenix",
      bookInSection: 6,
      authorNumber: 3
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      bookName: "Сказание о трех свинах",
      urlAddress: "The-Tale-of-the-Three-Pigs",
      bookInSection: 1,
      authorNumber: 4
    }
  ],

  booksAuthor: [{
      id: 1,
      authorName: "Борис",
      authorSurname: "Стругацкий"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      authorName: "Аркадий",
      authorSurname: "Стругацкий"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      authorName: "Джоан",
      authorSurname: "Роулинг"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      authorName: "Джон",
      authorSurname: "Толкиен"
    }
  ]
};

function Main(props) {
  const {
    booksDescription,
    booksAuthor
  } = props;

  return (

    <
    main className = {
      "main"
    } >
    <
    Route path = '/'
    exact render = {
      () => < WorkSpace / >
    }
    /> <
    Route path = '/audio-book/:urlAddress'
    render = {
      () => < BookArticle
      booksDescription = {
        booksDescription
      }
      booksReader = {
        booksReader
      }
      booksAuthor = {
        booksAuthor
      }
      booksCategories = {
        booksCategories
      }
      />}/ >
      <
      /main>

    );
  }

  function WorkSpace(props) {
    const {
      booksDescription,
      booksAuthor
    } = props;

    return ( <
      main className = {
        "main"
      } >
      <
      div id = "FullListBook" >
      <
      BookList booksDescription = {
        booksDescription
      }
      booksAuthor = {
        booksAuthor
      }
      /> <
      /div> <
      /main>
    );
  }

  function BookList(props) {
    const {
      booksDescription,
      booksAuthor
    } = props;

    let BooksList = booksDescription.map(el => ( <
      BookItem id = {
        el.id
      }
      urlAddress = {
        el.urlAddress
      }
      key = {
        el.id
      }
      bookName = {
        el.bookName
      }
      authorNumber = {
        el.authorNumber
      }
      />
    ));

    return BooksList;
  }

  class BookItem extends React.Component {

    render() {

      const book = this.props;
      const {
        booksReader,
        booksAuthor,
      } = this.props;


      const authorsOfBookNumber = book.authorNumber - 1;

      const authorOfBookName = booksAuthor[authorsOfBookNumber].authorName;
      const authorOfBookSurname = booksAuthor[authorsOfBookNumber].authorSurname;

      const authorsOfBookFull = authorOfBookSurname + " " + authorOfBookName;

      return ( <
        div className = "bl_book__item" >
        <
        NavLink className = "bl_book__link"
        to = {
          "audio-book/" + book.urlAddress
        } >
        <
        p className = "bl_book__name" >
        <
        p className = "bl_book__title" > {
          book.bookName
        } < /p> <
        p className = "bl_book__author" > {
          authorsOfBookFull
        } < /p> <
        /p> <
        /NavLink> <
        /div>
      );
    }
  }

  function BookArticle(props, match) {

    // const {
    //     booksDescription: {urlAddress}
    // } = match;
    //
    // let bookName = this.props.bookName;

    const {
      booksDescription,
      booksAuthor,
    } = this.props;

    return ( <
      h1 > < /h1>  
    )

  }

  import React, {
    Component
  } from "react";
  import {
    render
  } from "react-dom";
  import "./style.css";
  import {
    BrowserRouter
  } from "react-router-dom";
  import {
    NavLink
  } from "react-router-dom";

  function App(props) {
    return ( <
      WorkSpace booksDescription = {
        props.state.booksDescription
      }
      booksAuthor = {
        props.state.booksAuthor
      }
      />
    );
  }

  render( < BrowserRouter > < App state = {
      state
    }
    /></BrowserRouter > , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.bl_book__item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  max-resolution: 40px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

article {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/5.2.0/react-router.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

[Вот более рабочий код](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ksgnrw) *на локалке работал, тут почему-то ещё и ошибку при выводи списка выдает.

Задача простая - Как нажимая на элементы списка книг переходить по ссылке компонента который динамически формируется в `Route` ?

[image: Route элемента]

В качестве "ключа" параметра я пробую ориентироваться на URL книги `urlAddress` хотя в читаемых [примерах постоянно берут id](https://medium.com/@stasonmars/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE-react-router-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-1-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-1c159cca6fea). Я не понимаю, как правильно производить match данных хранимых в state
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
не получается вывести Имя нажатой книги

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот рабочий пример

```js
import React, {
  Component
} from "react";
import {
  render
} from "react-dom";
import {
  BrowserRouter
} from "react-router-dom";
import {
  NavLink,
  Route,
  withRouter
} from "react-router-dom";

let state = {
  booksDescription: [{
      id: 1,
      bookName: "Понедельник начинается в субботу",
      urlAddress: "Monday-starts-on-Saturday",
      bookInSection: 1,
      authorNumber: 2
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      bookName: "Гарри Поттер и Орден Феникса",
      urlAddress: "Harry-Potter-and-the-Order-of-the-Phoenix",
      bookInSection: 6,
      authorNumber: 3
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      bookName: "Сказание о трех свинах",
      urlAddress: "The-Tale-of-the-Three-Pigs",
      bookInSection: 1,
      authorNumber: 4
    }
  ],

  booksAuthor: [{
      id: 1,
      authorName: "Борис",
      authorSurname: "Стругацкий"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      authorName: "Аркадий",
      authorSurname: "Стругацкий"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      authorName: "Джоан",
      authorSurname: "Роулинг"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      authorName: "Джон",
      authorSurname: "Толкиен"
    }
  ]
};

function Main(props) {
  const {
    booksDescription,
    booksAuthor
  } = props;

  return (

      <
      main className = {
        "main"
      } >
      <
      Route path = '/'
      exact render = {
        () => < WorkSpace booksDescription = {
          booksDescription
        }
        booksAuthor = {
          booksAuthor
        }
        />}/ >
        <
        Route path = '/audio-book/:urlAddress'
        render = {
          () => < BookArticle
          booksDescription = {
            booksDescription
          }
          booksAuthor = {
            booksAuthor
          }
          />}/ >
          <
          /main>

        );
      }

      function WorkSpace(props) {
        const {
          booksDescription,
          booksAuthor
        } = props;

        return ( <
          main className = {
            "main"
          } >
          <
          div id = "FullListBook" >
          <
          BookList booksDescription = {
            booksDescription
          }
          booksAuthor = {
            booksAuthor
          }
          /> < /
          div > <
          /main>
        );
      }

      function BookList(props) {
        const {
          booksDescription,
          booksAuthor
        } = props;

        let BooksList = !booksDescription ? null : booksDescription.map(el => ( <
          BookItem id = {
            el.id
          }
          urlAddress = {
            el.urlAddress
          }
          key = {
            el.id
          }
          bookName = {
            el.bookName
          }
          authorNumber = {
            el.authorNumber
          }
          booksAuthor = {
            booksAuthor
          }
          />
        ));

        return BooksList;
      }

      class BookItem extends React.Component {

        render() {

          const book = this.props;
          const {
            booksReader,
            booksAuthor,
          } = this.props;


          const authorsOfBookNumber = book.authorNumber - 1;

          const authorOfBookName = booksAuthor[authorsOfBookNumber].authorName;
          const authorOfBookSurname = booksAuthor[authorsOfBookNumber].authorSurname;

          const authorsOfBookFull = authorOfBookSurname + " " + authorOfBookName;

          return ( <
            div className = "bl_book__item" >
            <
            NavLink className = "bl_book__link"
            to = {
              "audio-book/" + book.urlAddress
            } >
            <
            p className = "bl_book__name" >
            <
            p className = "bl_book__title" > {
              book.bookName
            } < /p> <
            p className = "bl_book__author" > {
              authorsOfBookFull
            } < /p> < /
            p > <
            /NavLink> < /
            div >
          );
        }
      }

      const BookArticle = withRouter((props) => {
        // const {
        //     booksDescription: {urlAddress}
        // } = match;
        //
        // let bookName = this.props.bookName;

        const {
          booksDescription,
          booksAuthor,
        } = props;

        console.log(props)

        return ( <
          h1 > {
            booksDescription.find(book => book.urlAddress === props.match.params.urlAddress).bookName
          } < /h1>  
        )

      })








      function App(props) {
        return ( <
          Main booksDescription = {
            props.state.booksDescription
          }
          booksAuthor = {
            props.state.booksAuthor
          }
          />
        );
      }

      render( < BrowserRouter > < App state = {
          state
        }
        /></BrowserRouter > , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.bl_book__item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  max-resolution: 40px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

article {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-FJ5AplytBPxdjAzUUTWdQ8TH/z+uNVH4nBC2KZQpXSUHFmWnPMbqvvEEEqB2Loadbtl5zimK3CQT/MD4IBED+w==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/5.2.0/react-router.min.js" integrity="sha512-sWGrnSIvNDdGRsqnFIm5q1uHjPt5912wNVBK9vChpbHPReP96giWBGeztcd/rva+n82nQLTJ1SFbZqLHbCqMiw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-FJ5AplytBPxdjAzUUTWdQ8TH/z+uNVH4nBC2KZQpXSUHFmWnPMbqvvEEEqB2Loadbtl5zimK3CQT/MD4IBED+w==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

[Тут рабочая версия задачи](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-grc1cv?file=index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы переходите на другую страницу то может передавать некоторые данные в URL страницы. Обычно это id или slug, забирать их через props.math.params. И основываясь на этих данных отправлять запрос на бэкенд для получения более подробных данных. Но если необходимо передавать полный объект данных то можете посмотреть в сторону context api.

Comment: Спасибо, за совет, но это не мой случай. Мне потом ещё состояния вешать на компонент, так что прогон props по всем компонентам меня впполне устраивает. Мне просто не понятно, как получить данные именно об нажатом элементе. Не знаю как правильно произвести match

Comment: У вас должны быть настроены роуты для всех сраниц на которые вы будете переходить. Пример <Route path="/books/:urlAddress/detail" component={BookDetailt} /> Здесь BookDetail это страница на которую вы переходите. На этой странице вы можете получить urlAddres c помощью porps.math.params.urlAddress.